# jquery.min.js not loading is the error I am getting after I am using the Google cdn in jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, css, visual-web-developer

I am just learning and checking if jQuery is working but I am unable to get the changes as it is showing unable to load I am using Google cdn and yes I have the script of it above my local js file

Javascript

```
 $("h1").css("color", "red");
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>jQuery</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <button>Click me</button>
    <button>Click me</button>
    <button>Click me</button>
    <button>Click me</button>
    <button>Click me</button>
    <script src="https://ajaxgoogleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Add this link `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js`

Answer (score 1):

It is ajax.googleapis.com not ajaxgoogleapis
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js